# Magento 2 : When creating a product - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails?

Tags: product, magento2.2, create-product

When creating a product, it throws this error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails  (`vbm`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) ON DELETE), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, '2019-02-13 05:46:17', '2019-02-13 05:46:17')
```

Comment: Are you creating product programmatically ?

Comment: yes i have tried multiple snippets but this error remain constant.

Comment: Please add your code, so I will guide you if any issue in your code

Answer (score 0):

The product you are trying to create has an attribute set which does not exist in your database. Therefore the foreign key error for `attribute_set_id`.

You can see your existing attribute sets for products with this SQL statement:

```
select * from  eav_attribute_set where entity_type_id = 4;`
```

If you try to create a product with an `attribute_set_id` which is not listed there, you will get that error.

But anyway it would be good if you post the code you are using, so we can doublecheck it.

Comment: @Abdul Rafay You're welcome. Did it solve your problem or do you need further help?

Comment: The problem has been solved, i was try to associate the product to the attribute set which didn't exists.